# How do I deal with prototype classes when working with typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdata

Let's suggest that I have a data library that handles most of my object management.
For each resource it allows me to choose a base class to which it adds it's own prototype functions to.

So for example If I have,

```
  interface IJob
  {
     openJob();
  }
  class Job : IJob
  {
     openJob() => {console.log('open');}
  }
```

then create my Job via
Store.job.create(); 
it returns a instance of the class but it also decorates it with prototype functions like .save(), .update(), etc

The problem is that if I try to use .save() on the job instance, it's undefined because the interface doesn't define it. Now if I do define it, it expects me to define .save/.update in the class which I don't really want to do because the store is already adding prototype functions to the class.

Is there a best way to handle this?

For reference I'm trying to use js-data as my data store library.

Answer (score 2):

> Now if I do define it, it expects me to define .save/.update in the class which I don't really want to do because the store is already adding prototype functions to the class.

What are you looking for is mixins. And there are official links for mixins: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Mixins.md which shows *that you do need to declare these in the class even though you don't define them* (and they get mixed in).